# Plotting by iteration in R

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I am working on a project that requires I have 20 different bar charts. I have found that I can plot them one by one, but am looking for a more efficient way to do this in the future if a similar problem comes up.

I have tried a standard for loop, but my plots all come up empty.

```
    library(lattice)
    par(mfrow = c(1,1))
    b_clr <- c("steelblue", "darkred")


    for(i in 1:20){
      png(paste(i,'.png', sep = ''))


    barchart(as.table(V[[i]]),
        main = map$V1[i],
        horizontal = FALSE,
        col = ifelse(V[[i]] > 0,
                     b_clr[1],
                     b_clr[2]),
        ylab = "Impact Value",
        scales = list(x=list(relation = "free",
                             rot = 55,
                             labels = top.df[[i]],
                             cex = 1.1)))
    dev.off()
    }
```

If I take this out of the loop, and change all the i's to individual values, the plots work just fine. But, if I run them as a loop I get no plots. Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide some data to mirror?

Comment: This is essentially a request that we read R-FAQ 7.22 https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f to you. Try reading the rest of the FAQ.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that the FAQ page existed. That opens up a greatly appreciated new resource for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your call to barchart with `print()` like this:

```
library(lattice)
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
b_clr <- c("steelblue", "darkred")

for(i in 1:3){

  png(paste(i,'test.png', sep = ''))

  map <- iris[i * c(1, 2, 3),]  

  print(barchart(map$Petal.Length,
           main = i,
           horizontal = FALSE,
           col = ifelse(map$Petal.Length > 0,
                        b_clr[1],
                        b_clr[2]),
           ylab = "Impact Value"))
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't know that print had to be explicitly called within a function or loop

Comment: Could you explain why `print(plot)` works whereas `plot()` does not? It clearly works...I just don't understand why.

Comment: @ChiPak I'm taking this directly from the manual mentioned above: `Lattice functions such as xyplot() create a graph object, but do not display it ... The print() method for the graph object produces the actual display. `

Comment: Thanks for the info